# VS2012 + CRM 2011: Microsoft.IdentityModel bad reference

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2011

I've downloaded the [CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) and am following the instructions to get up and running, using the C# quickstart project.  When I try to build it, VS complains of a reference to the above assembly, which does not appear to be on my PC (Windows 8), certainly not where expected according to the reference in the project file.  When I tried to install Microsoft Identity Model it refused, indicating that it was already installed by being integrated with .NET framework 4.5.

I'm not sure where to go next - can anyone help, please?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the advice.  I downloaded the free trial of VS2012 specially for the CRM work.  Do you recommend that I download a VS2010 copy as well?

Comment: @Alex Would you care to elaborate on this one, please? I'm about to take the step to the ugliness called VS12 right now and as far I've seen there's a version of the SDK and developer toolkit for VS12. It's actually called *crmdevelopertoolsvs12_installer*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Hm, I didn't notice the new SDK version. Clearing the previous comment, anyway I can't help but notice `Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008` and `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010`.

Comment: Good point. Might it be a forgotten text from before? I'd guess that it's more likely that they forgot to change the old formulation, than that they happen to create and distribute a file with *12* in the name. But still, valid point, let me stress. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 bundles the Windows Identity Foundation 3.5. However, it is not enabled by default.
See [Quick tip: Enable Windows Identity Foundation (Windows 8)](http://blog.xrm.com/index.php/2012/10/quick-tip-enable-windows-identity-foundation-windows-8/) for a description.

After that the reference should be found.

The [latest version of WIF is part of .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx), so there is no dedicated installer anymore. WIF 3.5 is needed for CRM because it was an additional SDK for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. As CRM is based on .NET 4 this is the route to follow.

I don't know why they don't have a separate installer for Windows 8 and why they have bundled it with Windows 8. Maybe this is the reason: [Windows 8 and .Net Framework 3.5](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5.aspx)

Comment: I'm surprised. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331) I got version 6.1 (for Win 7) and [here](http://blog.nimbo.com/how-to-install-windows-identity-foundation-wif-4-0/), they talk about version 4.0. Why would Win 8 come with an old version? Or does it depend on what version of Win 8 one has?!

Comment: Good link. A bit heavy to scrutinized but the main point is that there are parts of .NET 3½ that are still at large. One'd think that by Win8, the move to .NET 4 would be complete. I guess I'll stand corrected on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Download & install the windows identity foundation from the following link

[Identity Model Problem Fix](http://crmprof.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/ms-crm-2011-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-exception/)

Comment: This download is not valid for Windows 8. However it is necessary for Vista or Windows 7